# Migrating from SCCS to Git

Tags: git, version-control, solaris

I have a development environment running on a Solaris 10 box.  The vcs used is currently SCCS.  It is planned to move this environment to a new box running Solaris 11.  I was thinking of using this as an opportunity to move to a new vcs system, most likely Git.

I was wondering is it a case that we would have to just start fresh on the other box with a dump of the current repo from the old box or is it possible to preserve the repo history?

I have done a bit of searching SCCS to Git information seems quite scarce.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There seems to be a “SCCS2Git” script, mentioned [here](http://search.cpan.org/~hmbrand/VCS-SCCS-0.24/SCCS.pm#TODO). It’s in the TODO section, so one can only guess its status, but the sourcecode is available and it was “recently” (in 2015) [moved to GitHub](https://github.com/Tux/VCS-SCCS) where it’s somewhat actively maintained (as in: There are recent commits). If you can figure out how it works, maybe you can give it a try (after backing things up obviously).

Otherwise I would probably go a less experimental route and convert to something else first. Git has a good interface to Subversion, and there seem to be a good number of converters from SCCS to Subversion, for example [this](http://sccs2svn.berlios.de/). If you set up a local Subversion repository, you can probably export the data quickly and then import it as a new Git repository using [git-svn](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-svn.html).

Comment: Like the svn intermediate migration path. +1

Comment: Thanks poke I think the SCCS>SVN>Git might be the best course of action.  I will look into this.

Comment: The link under `here` returns a `404`

Answer (score 2):

You *could* try and execute a script like **[sccs2git](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/HMBRAND/VCS-SCCS-0.24/examples/sccs2git-r)**, trying to import the full history into a new Git repo.

However, it is best to check if the content of that legacy repo wouldn't be best managed in *several* Git repos (split), and if you can only import the last meaningful labels (which makes for a shorter import process), while keeping the legacy repo in read-only mode for archive.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the repository layout. I didn’t think of that—but then again, I have no idea about SCCM ;)

Comment: at line 91 I had to divide the timezone value by 36: $tzoffset->($delta{stamp}) / 36.  I was getting numbers like -18000 which should have been -0500 (for CDT).  git threw a fatal error otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

The need to do this must be increasingly rare, but I needed to do it today, for a curses-based program from 1986. (Surprisingly, it needed very little tweaking to make it run on a modern system.)

I came here looking for an answer, but neither of the two previous ones worked for me, mostly because the scripts and utilities linked to are unmaintained or no longer exist. However, I did find a good solution so I'm writing it down for any poor souls that still need to do this.

The overall plan is SCCS -> RCS -> CVS -> git. The unusual part is getting from SCCS to RCS, but Eric Raymond's [sccs2rcs](http://www.catb.org/esr/sccs2rcs/) is maintained and works well. It's a Python script that uses only the core libraries, so is easy to install and is unlikely to break in the future. It depends on having `sccs` and `rcs` commands available, but these are typically available through third-party packaging systems (eg distro/homebrew). In the case of `sccs`, I used [CSSC](http://www.gnu.org/software/cssc/).

Once you reach RCS, the path is more well-trodden. To convert a directory hierarchy containing `RCS` subdirectories into a CVS repository, you just have to move the `,v` RCS files up one level out of those subdirectories and add an empty `CVSROOT` directory at the top level.

To get from CVS to git, I used the well-maintained [cvs2svn](https://www.mcs.anl.gov/%7Ejacob/cvs2svn/) utility (widely available as a third-party package). It provides a `cvs2git` script that works by generating blobs for use by `git fast-import`. It works well, but is a little quirky in how it has to be configured. You have to copy the `cvs2git-example.options` file and tweak it for your needs. I changed the directory in `run_options.set_project` to be `.` and added name(s) to the author mappings in `author_transforms`.

I tied the RCS -> git steps together with the following script:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

set -e

MYDIR=$(dirname "$0")

# Move RCS files out of RCS subdirectories
find * -name RCS -type d |
while read RCS
do
    mv -i $RCS/*,v $(dirname $RCS)
    rmdir $RCS
done

# Create git import
mkdir -p CVSROOT
cvs2git --options="$MYDIR/cvs2git.options"
rmdir CVSROOT

# Import to git
git init -b master
cat cvs2git-tmp/git-blob.dat cvs2git-tmp/git-dump.dat | git fast-import
rm -r cvs2git-tmp
git reset --mixed

# Fix up $Id$ keywords
git ls-files | xargs -r sed --in-place '/$Id:/s/\([0-9]\)\//\1-/g'

# Back up RCS files
mkdir -p RCS-backup
find * -path RCS-backup -prune -o -name \*,v -print | cpio -pdml RCS-backup
find * -path RCS-backup -prune -o -name \*,v -print0 | xargs -0 -r rm -f
```

This will probably work for most people, but you do need to create `cvs2git.options` by editing a copy of `cvs2git-example.options` from the contrib directory of the `cvs2svn` package.